# What is the difference between nanomaterials and quantum materials?

Tags: experimental-physics, nanoscience, quantum-dots

As per my knowledge, they are different according to their dimensions only. Can you please explain if I am missing something?

Answer (score 1):

As per Wikipedia [Nanomaterials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanomaterials):

> Nanomaterials describe, in principle, materials of which a single unit is sized (in at least one dimension) between 1 and 100 nm (the usual definition of nanoscale).

whereas [Quantum materials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_materials):

> Quantum materials is an umbrella term in condensed matter physics that encompasses all materials whose essential properties cannot be described in terms of semiclassical particles and low-level quantum mechanics.

Nanoscale objects generally exhibit quantum properties, but they don't have to, or these properties may not be the focus of interest. E.g., a macroscopic object, like an aircraft or a spaceship, may be made of *nanomaterials* - what it means here is that the purity of material is controlled on the nanoscale level, and possibly it is even made of nanoscale size elements - like [carbon nanotubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_nanotube) or [fullerenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckminsterfullerene). But the material itself is macroscopic, and we are interested in its macroscopic (and very much classical=not quantum) properties - like rigidity, elasticity, etc.

In case of *quantum materials*, like quantum dots, quantum wires, single-molecule devices, etc. one is studying and using their quantum nature/behavior. E.g., in a computer chip with nanoscale elements each elements performs its own function, obeying quantum laws.